# DDWRT PPTP Client and OpenVPN server at sametime

Tags: vpn, openvpn, dd-wrt, pptp

Is it possible to configure one DDWRT (Linksys E900) as PPTP client and OpenVPN server at the same time?

The OpenVPN server is configured OK with TAP. How do I configure the PPTP client on same router? How do i know the pptp tunnel is Up like OpenVpn tab on Status?

Comment: Exists many tutorials explaining a problem with PPTP client on DDWRT. Anyone help me.

Comment: DDWRT V24 PreSP2 21061